# Why does toLowerCase() does not work with replace()?

Tags: javascript

Given Below is a simple function to capitalize the first words in a sentence
**Eg: INPUT: 'JavaSCRipt is The BEST'

OUTPUT: 'JavaScript Is The Best'**

```
const firstupper = function(str){
    const arr = str.split(' ');
    const newArr = [];
    for(let item of arr){
        item = item.toLowerCase();
        newArr.push(item.replace(item[0], item[0].toUpperCase()));
    }
    const newstr = newArr.join(' ');
    console.log(newstr);
}

firstupper('javaSCript is THE besT');
```

P.S -- This code works fine

Why can't I make to lower case and then replace the first letter in upper case in single line
like : `newArr.push(item.toLowerCase().replace(item[0], item[0].toUpperCase()));`

When I write the code using this it is changing the first word to lower if it is in upper case vice versa

**Eg: INPUT -> 'JAvaScript is The best'
OUTPUT - > 'javascript Is the Best'**

Answer (score 3):

Because that changes the logic.  In this version, *all* reads of `item` in the `.push()` operation are lower-cased:

```
item = item.toLowerCase();
newArr.push(item.replace(item[0], item[0].toUpperCase()));
```

But in this version, only the *first* use of `item` is lower-cased:

```
newArr.push(item.toLowerCase().replace(item[0], item[0].toUpperCase()));
```

The references to `item[0]` both still use whatever the original casing was.  To make it the same logic you'd need to repeat the case change there as well:

```
newArr.push(item.toLowerCase().replace(item.toLowerCase()[0], item.toLowerCase()[0].toUpperCase()));
```

Which clearly is too cluttered and unnecessarily repeats the operation.  So the original working version is preferred.

Comment: What do you mean by first use is lowercased.
Also, can we use brackets around (item.toLowerCase()).replace.........   would this work

Comment: @AbhishekPragada: The line of code with the push operation reads the item variable three times.  In the working example that variable is first replaced with a lower cased copy of its value, so all three uses of the value see the lower cased version.  In the non-working version it is never replaced.  The lower casing operation happens in-line and only happens once, so only that use is lower cased.  The remaining two uses of the item variable are reading its original, non-lowercased value.  No, using parentheses would not change this.

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
const str = 'JavaSCRipt is The BEST';

//split the above string into an array of strings 
//whenever a blank space is encountered

const arr = str.split(" ");

//loop through each element of the array and capitalize the first letter.


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);

}

//Join all the elements of the array back into a string 
//using a blankspace as a separator 
const str2 = arr.join(" ");
console.log(str2);

//Outptut: Javascript Is The Best
```